# File path Issue in HTML?

Tags: html, css

The link to the page: http://jensglobaltravel.com/orig-index.html
The file path that my editor gave me for the north-america destination page: 
destinations/north-america/north-america.html

I'll select a page from the Destinations Tab on the top navigation bar of the page for instance "North america" Once on north america when I try to go to any of the destination pages on the top navigation bar none of them take me anywhere or are even clickable. The think that really makes me wonder is that when you hover over one of the links on the destination tab on the navigation bar on one of the destination pages It shows the correct file path in the bottom left corner of chrome.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am very confused!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the HTML looks fine.  There is a javascript click handler on the top nav links that is stopping the navigation event.  The module is called "UIToTop" in the js/core.min.js file.  This is probably attached by line 1677 of /js/script.js

Comment: Thank you i'll give that a go!